# How to return the results from a coroutine object with asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm attempting to learn how to run asynchronous code in google co-labs with asyncio. However, I am having issues returning the results.

An example I set up for myself looks like this:

```
async def main():
  task = asyncio.create_task(other_function())
  print("1")
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print("2")
  await task

async def other_function():
  print('A')
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print('B')

asyncio.run(main())
```

This results in the error "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop"

I determined that because of the way google co-labs runs its event loops, asyncio.run() was not necessary and attempted to re-run the code with this part removed.

However, by changing the bottom line to just main() instead of asyncio.run(main()) the output is "<coroutine object main at 0x79c6076fa500>". Which is not what I'm looking for.

In theory the output should be

```
1
A
2
B
```

As of yet, I have been unable to find a solution. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google-colab, just put `await main()` at the end:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
  task = asyncio.create_task(other_function())
  print("1")
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print("2")
  await task

async def other_function():
  print('A')
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print('B')

await main()
```

Output:

```
1
A
2
B
```